# ExtJS 6.2 Отложенная отрисовка Panel из данных store

Tags: extjs

Возникли сложности при отрисовке items компонента Ext.form.Panel.

Вот код:

```
Ext.define('Client.help.News', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'help_news',

    title: 'Новости',
    bodyPadding: 20,
    layout: 'accordion',
    items: [],

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        this.store = Ext.create('Client.store.News');   
        this.store.load({
            scope: this,
            callback: function() {
                me.store.each(function(record) {
                    me.items.add({
                        title: record.get('title'),
                        html: record.get('text')
                    });
                }); 
            }
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);             
    }
});
```

Не понимаю как добавить данные после загрузки из store в items.
Очень прошу помочь.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно было вызвать `me.add` вместо `me.items.add`, так как этот метод у Panel а не у массива items.